# Configuring a Log4Net logger using AppSettings

Tags: c#, log4net, config

I'm currently switching the logging system of a project away from a homemade logger to Log4Net. Under the previous logger we had created, AppSettings.config contained keys to control whether the app logged to the console, a file, or both. Now, using Log4Net, we will be logging to console, file, and database. Also, I have the configuration for Log4Net set up in an external config, so the files concerned are App.config, Log4Net.config, and AppSettings.config.

My question: Will it be possible to continue using keys from AppSettings to control the combination of these three methods used? I know I can create a set of loggers covering the different combinations, but controlling it directly through AppSettings seems far more efficient, and would be my preferred method of doing things.

Thank you very much for your help and expertise.

Comment: I don't think `AppSettings.config` is a standard file, can you show how you currently load settings out of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can in your Log4Net.config configure how you want to get the output.
It is possible to get to logging to all three types.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to configure log4net to use your AppSettings.config out of the box, but you can write your own Configurator and manually add appenders to your Loggers at runtime as outlined [here](http://dhvik.blogspot.com/2008/08/adding-appender-to-log4net-in-runtime.html). It is still some extra overhead to avoid what log4net gives you anyway. What is the benefit of using AppSettings.config as you see it?

Comment: One advantage of log4net config options within the <appSettings></appSettings> section is they can be easily overridden in Azure for your application (App Services | Application Settings).